# Is the Force Touch Trackpad on MacBook Pro supposed to be 'nudged' with a mechanical clicking sound?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

Yesterday I received a brand new MacBook Pro Touch Mid-2017 with Touchbar, which was built-to-order.

Before even passing through the setup screens, I noticed that the Force Touch Trackpad gives away a mechanical thud/clicking sound at each press. At every press, the Trackpad is nudged down/slightly lowered, and this is what creates the mechanical sound. The same thing happens regardless of where on the Force Trackpad's area I press.

I was under the impression that Trackpad are supposed to be non-movable and completely static, and that any tactile and audio feedback is purely from the haptic engine and speakers. I am entirely sure that the sound is mechanical and coming from the Trackpad, not the speakers.

Is this a manufacturing problem?

Here is a video of the sound (the nudge is very slight so it may not be visible in the video): https://youtu.be/gyIG8gAn6B0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video quality is such that the nudge is not really visible. But yes, the intention is that the trackpad should not physically move in normal circumstances.

The clicking sound on the video however sounds pretty much like it should. The sound is generated by the computer - it is not mechanical.

You could consider taking the computer to a store and comparing the sound with another MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

After going to a Mac store and comparing the click of the Force Touch Trackpad to those of other Macs, I have reached the conclusion that the nudge and sound is normal.

However, all of the Force Touch Trackpads I pressed on, did in fact nudge downwards ever so slightly in the way I mentioned – on both MacBooks and MacBook Pros. I don't know if the haptic engine was responsible for this, but to me it was very clear that there is a visibly small nudge downwards and not just a tactile feedback (like 3D touch on iPhones for instance). So the claim that Force Touch Trackpads don't move at all, to me appears misconstruing.

Comment: It is honestly an illusion. The haptic engine does indeed give the impression of movement.  It is VERY convincing, but the only moving part is the engine underneath the trackpad. This can be [turned off.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352) "On Mac notebooks made before 2016, you can turn off the sound of your trackpad's click by selecting Silent clicking." Although with it off one can still hear the engine although muted.

Comment: yes, the haptic engine itself is the source of the sound

Answer (score -1):

It is normal, check another of the latest MacBook Pros. The trackpad is not moving. An haptic feedback is generated so you can feel the click, and a click sound is generated as an audio confirmation that you actually did click on something. Hope this helps.